# Windows XP not recognizing eSATA connections

Tags: windows-xp, esata

I've just downgraded to WinXP Professional (SP3) from Vista.  Install was to a brand new Caviar Black 1TB drive.  My machine has eSATA connectors on the back and on the front.  I have a XION eSATA HDD dock (XON-SAHDCB-COMBOCR) that was working fine under Vista Ultimate.  The eSATA connection is not being recognized by XP at all.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that the controller for your eSATA ports is turned on in the BIOS, that the mode is set to AHCI and that you've got the drivers for that specific controller installed. On my ASUS motherboard, the eSATA port has it's own controller.

Comment: I have an ASUS M3N-HT Deluxe.  Where is the eSATA in the BIOS?  Which section should it be in?  I just spent 15 minutes in there and couldn't find it.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need to find the eSata Bus Adapter Driver.  If you open the "system" applet in control panel you can go to the hardware manager tab and open the properties dialog.  Hardware Manager should indicate which devices on the system do not have drivers.  In many cases you can extract the exact device type from what is listed in the dialog box.  Other times you might need to crack open the case and read off the exact model number when the first method does not work.

At this point, go out to the web, go to the manufacturers support page, get the drive and finally install.  After this, you should be good to go!